# Freescale CodeWarrior : Register watchpoint on HCS08

Tags: watchpoint, codewarrior, 68hc11

I need to break the debugging when I-bit of SR (global interrupt mask) changes it's state.

Freescale CodeWarrior 6.1

MCU: HCS08

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?